# Why did Typescript allow me to create an object without specifying required fields?

Tags: typescript

I created a class, then through the constructor I created an instance of the object from this class. The object was successfully created and output to the console, the file was compiled into .js, BUT: why didn’t I get the error that "Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Vehicle': isSpecial, brand, model, and 2 more." ? In the class description these fields are not optional, but nevertheless I was able to create an object without indicating them, there was no error. But when I create an object like this: "const toyota: Vehicle = {}", there is an error. Through the constructor - no error. Why?

```
class Vehicle {
  isSpecial: boolean;
  wheels: number;
  brand: string;
   model: string;
   mileage: number;
   isUsed: boolean;
   constructor (wheels: number, mileage: number) {
     this.wheels = wheels;
     this.mileage = mileage;
   }
   drive(): void {
     this.mileage += 100;
   };
 }

 const toyota: Vehicle = new Vehicle(4, 200);

 console.log(toyota);
```

Expected: error "Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Vehicle': isSpecial, brand, model, and 2 more."
Actual: no errors, object created

Answer (score 2):

You have to turn on `--strictPropertyInitialization` [compiler option](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#strict-class-initialization), then you will get errors [highlighting uninitialized properties](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBqCmALAlqe0DeAoa1kQGUAHeYZMEALmgCMB7OkeMAOwG4doB3ReeECNRYBXALY14AJw64ak1gBNqEAC6TkLAOYzcougv7K1G7Z2ijkTMJvhCxE6WfwBVCPCW0GV9meB0WqpLCwCp0ktAAFDx8AnbiUgA05pbMNnEOAJSYZrgqKBAAdNH8MAC83LwlOrjQefgFFlY20OWNqfDVAL5mCuoAbvARGdR9dMgK2TW5+Q0p1ugA1OUAjAAMq10y3Th+ASq1dACedCpg1AgoaC3QLPBccEioTBEALEkATOsZHDv+EIzwAogOiaCKhY6nb5AA).

Answer (score 0):

```js
  isSpecial: boolean;
  wheels: number;
  brand: string;
   model: string;
   mileage: number;
   isUsed: boolean;
```

These are not declarations that they are required. These are declarations that you state are available to you. Not all instance variables inside `this` have to be declared in the `constructor`, so typescript don't enforce its declaration in it. The only things that are absolutely required are the things you put as arguments to your `constructor` function